# Setting id of OneToMany relationship when persisting entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a hibernate application, where I want to persist an owner.

One owner can have many animals

(inside Owner entity)

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
private List<Animal> animals;
```

(inside Animal entity)

```
  @ManyToOne
private Owner owner;
```

I have a repository, where I persist my owner,

```
   @Override
public Owner create(String name, String email, int age, 
List<Animal> animals) {
    Owner owner = new Owner(name, email, age, animals);
    for(Animal animal: animals){
        animal.setOwner(owner);
    }
    getEntityManager().persist(owner);
    return owner;
}
}
```

the owner is persisted correctly, but the foreign key is not set in the animal table.

I used the debugger to check that the owner is set correctly for the animal which it is.

First, I tried persisting the animal which caused an error

```
   for(Animal animal: animals){
        animal.setOwner(owner);
        getEntityManager().persist(animal)
    } //caused an error
```

so I thought about using a type of cascade, to make sure, the animal gets the Owner id into the database,

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Animal> animals;
```

this caused an error as well

```
 "cause": {
  "detailMessage": "detached entity passed to persist: com.tolboll.zoo.data.entities.Animal",
  "stackTrace": [],
  "suppressedExceptions": []
},
```

how can i make it so, that the owner is correctly persisted into the animal entity?

EDIT:

here is the JSON body passed in

```
  {
    "name": "kristoffer",
    "email": "Kristofferlocktolboll@gmail.com",
    "age": 23,
    "animals": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Simba",
        "weight": 110,
        "species": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Lion"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: How do you build the `List<Animal> animals` provided to `create` method? Also, do you have some kind of versioning?

Comment: @Eugen Covaci The animal list is passed in, in the JSON body

Comment: The `animals` list already exist in the database?

Comment: Yes it does Eugen.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I think it would be possible with the same transaction..

Comment: I suppose you do have a foreign key from Animal table to Owner table.

Comment: The error is clear, you are trying to persist a detached entity: Animal.

Comment: No i have a unidirectional relationship

Comment: How do you link an animal to its owner in the database?

Comment: well each owner has a list of animals, in the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you are trying to persist a detached entity: Animal.

**Solution**

In the Owner entity, leave as it is (although  `CascadeType.MERGE` is enough):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Animal> animals;
```

Then, in the `create` method, replace `persist` by `merge`:

```
getEntityManager().merge(owner);
```

The reason for that is the merge operation that you need for the `animals` list.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is merge, used, because, it needs to merge (update,), the animal list aswell?

Comment: @baileyhaldwin Yes.